# Two conjectures regarding $\varphi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, conjectures

There is a famous unsolved problem called [Lehmer's Totient Problem](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLehmer%2527s_totient_problem&ei=st-LVNzDM5WfugSN-oBw&usg=AFQjCNF7lqQlcjXrhrI7SQDsa03tzufv-w&bvm=bv.81828268,d.c2E) which states that,

> $\varphi(n)\mid n-1 \implies n$ is a prime.

Where $\varphi(n)$ is [Euler's Totient Function](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEuler%2527s_totient_function&ei=GeCLVM3iHdeJuATqpYCICQ&usg=AFQjCNEiOioKzQOZbW4mWqBZ0vZtWjZRGQ&bvm=bv.81828268,d.c2E).

I was wondering about two conjectures of my own which I found unable to prove or disprove  myself. The conjectures are,

> **Conjecture 1**
>
> If $n$ is an odd integer then $\varphi(n)+1\mid n \implies n$ is a prime.
>
> **Conjecture 2**
>
> For odd $n$, $\varphi(n)+1\mid n\iff \varphi(n)\mid n-1$

Note that both the conjectures are independent of one another and the proof of any one willn't shed light on the proof of disproof the other unless a proof or disproof of Lehmer's original conjecture is done.

So, can anyone help me in proving anyone of the conjectures?

---

**Note:-**

I don't know whether my conjectures are already well-known conjectures or not. If that's the case then any reference to the authentic source(s) will be enough.

---

**Added:-**

The conjectures are now edited taking in view the suggestions of fretty and A. Nicolas.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173908/updates-on-lehmers-totient-problem

Comment: Before making a conjecture you should always test it. You clearly haven't done this since an extremely small counter-example exists. As mentioned below $\phi(6) = 2$ and this divides $6$...

Comment: @fretty: I have checked the first conjecture for a small number of values but I didn't make it precise. Sorry for the confusion caused. Please let me know if there are other problems in the question.

Answer (score 5):

The conjecture should be modified, since for example if $n=2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime, then $\varphi(n)+1$ divides $n$.

Comment: Question edited. Thanks for the suggestion.