# On Composite Numbers of the Form $p_{1}p_{2} \ldots p_{k} - 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factoring, conjectures

This question is related to D. H. Lehmer's 1932 conjecture on Euler's totient function: Are there any composite $n$ for which $\phi(n)$ divides $n-1$?

See, for example:

[On Lehmer's Totient Conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075563/lehmers-conjecture-lehmers-totient-problem)

I would like to ask what is known regarding the factors of $p_{1}p_{2} \ldots p_{k} - 1$, where the $p_{i}$ are distinct odd prime numbers?

I was not able to find much in some number theory books I consulted.

Thank you.

Comment: It's known that $2$ is a factor; it's known that $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k$ aren't factors; it's hard to say anything else in general, as it's going to depend on what $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k$ are. Also, there are no conjectures on integers $n$ dividing $n-1$; the conjecture concerns $\phi(n)$ dividing $n-1$.

Comment: You came back to edit, but you did nothing about "integers $n$ dividing $n-1$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some additional things related Lehmer's totient conjecture that is known.

**Definition**: If $n$ is composite then $\phi(n)<n−1$, hence there is at least one divisor $d$ of $n−1$ which does not divide $\phi(n)$. We call $d$ as the totient divisor of $n$. Trivially, if $n$ is prime then it has no totient divisor and if $n−1$ is prime then $n$ has exactly 1 totient divisor.

> 1. [There at least 4 divisors of $n-1$ which do not divide $\phi(n)$ if
>      $n$ is a composite of the form $6k+1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245370/there-at-least-4-divisors-of-n-1-which-do-not-divide-phin-if-n-is-a-com).
> 2. [Odd numbers prefer not to have a prime number of totient divisors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248248/unknown-bias-in-a-distribution-related-to-prime-numbers).