# Show there are only a finite number of integers with $\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)} $ an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Show, for each $n$, there are only a finite number of integral $(a_i)_{i=1}^n$ such that $2\le a_i \le a_{i+1}$ and $\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)} $ is an integer.

My question is inspired by this one:

[Prove the fractions aren't integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800384/prove-the-fractions-arent-integers)

I can show that
$a_1
\le \dfrac1{2^{1/n}-1}
$.

I think there is a proof by induction
of the general case,
but I don't have one now.

A comment:
This reminds me of
the Egyptian fraction
problem.

Here's what I have now.

$\begin{array}\\
r
&=\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)+\prod_{i=1}^n a_i-\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)}\\
&=1+\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n a_i-\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)}\\
&=1+\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n (b_i+1)-\prod_{i=1}^n b_i-1}{\prod_{i=1}^n b_i}
\quad\text{where }b_i = a_i-1\\
\end{array}
$

Letting
$B = \prod_{i=1}^n b_i
$,
the fraction is,
dividing the numerator and denominator 
by $B$,
$r-1
=s
=\prod_{i=1}^n (1+1/b_i)-1-1/B
$.

We have
$s 
\gt 1+\sum_{i=1}^n 1/b_i-1-1/B
=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/b_i-1/B
\gt 0
$
since
$b_i \le B$
and $n \ge 2$.

Therefore,
if $s < 1$,
$r$ is not an integer.

If
$c_i = 1/b_i$,
$s 
= \prod_{i=1}^n (1+c_i)-1-\prod_{i=1}^n c_i
$,
so
$\dfrac{ds}{dc_j}
=\prod_{i=1, i\ne j}^n (1+c_i)-\prod_{i=1,i\ne j}^n c_i
$,
so that
$s$ 
is an increasing function of each $c_i$
and so is a decreasing function of each $b_i$.

In particular,
$s
\le (1+1/b_1)^n-1-1/b_1^n
$,
so that if
$(1+1/b_1)^n-1
\le 1$,
$s$ is not an integer.
This is
$1+1/b_1
\le 2^{1/n}
$
or
$b_1
\ge \dfrac1{2^{1/n}-1}
$.

Comment: Yes, if you start too big, then you get a fraction between 1 and 2. But you can always start with $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_k=2$ to pump up the size. So I don't think a pure size argument is going to work in the general case.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $a_1=\ldots=a_n=2$ produces an integer for all $n\in\Bbb N$ already show that there are infinitely many such  $(n; a_1,\ldots, a_n)$? Or is the question whether there are only finitely many solutions for each $n$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If $n$ isn't fixed then this would be far stronger than the best known upper bounds for the number of counterexamples to Lehmer's conjecture.

Comment: I should have made it clear that n is fixed.