# $abcd-1$ is divisible by $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)$.

Tags: number-theory

Find positive integers $(a, b, c, d)$ such that

$abcd-1$ is divisible by $(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)$.

My attempts :

WLOG, let $a<b<c<d$.

Since $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, $abcd-1 > (a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)$.

So $\frac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} > 1$

And $\frac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} <\frac{a}{a-1}\cdot\frac{b}{b-1}\cdot\frac{c}{c-1}\cdot\frac{d}{d-1}\leq \frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{5}{4} = 5$

So $\frac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}= 2$ or $3$ or $4$

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: How do you know that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct?

Comment: Taking $a = b = c = d = 2$ gives $(a - 1) \cdots (d - 1) = 1$, and every integer is divisible by $1$.

Comment: If one of a,b,c,d is odd, then all of them must be odd.

Comment: And if one is even, all of them are even.

Comment: @Paul That directly follows from what I said...

Comment: @TMM, sure, but it needed to be said.

Comment: @quasi, I may be wrong.  I think it would be harder if a, b, c, d are not necessary distinct.

Comment: @Paul Then let me "add" another insightful comment: either all are odd, or all are even. That really needed to be said.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173908/updates-on-lehmers-totient-problem

Comment: A solution with distinct values: 3,5,17,255

Comment: Is this your own variant of a problem proposed in the shortlist of the IMO 1992?

Comment: Note that $a,b,c,d$ must be either all odd or all even.
Here are solutions $(a,b,c,d)$ listed in non-decreasing order:
$$\mbox{even: }\ \ 
(2,2,2,2), \quad
(2,2,2,8), \quad
(2,2,4,4), \\
(2,2,6,24), \quad
(2,4,10,80); \\
\mbox{odd: }\ \ 
(3,3,3,3), \quad
(3,5,17,255).
$$

Now it remains to prove that there are no other solutions using a suitable upper bound for the ratio
$$
\frac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}.
$$

Comment: Apparently $abcd$ must be a perfect square.

Comment: @Alex comment disproves the last equation in the OP. $2,2,2,8$ gives $63/7$ which isn't one of $2,3,4$

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ aren't distinct the upper bound for $\frac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$ is 16. You can see this by modifying $2/1 * 3/2 * 4/3 * 5/4$ in OP to $(2/1)^4$.

Comment: @carat , May you give the condition for $a,b,c,d $ different. Other hand, if $a \le b \le c \le d$, then upper bound will be $16$. In this case, OP will include very exhaustive steps of the sub-cases. 

If $$a < b < c < d$$, I can find something for you.

Comment: @Xam, this problem is from past Math camp lesson.

Comment: @scarface, for the condition a<b<c<d, I still don't know that, if we know the upper bound of one variable, how can we solve for the other three variables manually ? Please show your solution. Thank you.

Comment: @carat , I send the solution of 1992 IMO problem. The problem has three varibles with $1<a<b<c$. Firstly, you may look this: 

http://i.hizliresim.com/nRo0JV.png

Comment: @scarface, thank you so much. I'm trying to study it.

Comment: @carat , examining of all cases are very long. So, I'm writing partial solution. I hope that these are useful for you.

Comment: It might be useful to focus on those cases where the solution exists; then write something like "Other cases are analyzed similarly and produce no solutions." This way the answer will be shorter and easier to read.

Comment: @Alex, I wonder, how can you get those solutions in your first post of this thread ? Thanks.

Comment: I got the solutions from numeric search with a PARI/GP program. (At first, I 
 stopped the search too early and missed a couple of solutions; after a longer search I got all of them.)

Answer (score 2):

I will solve the problem under the condition $1<a<b<c<d$.

Let's say $S=\dfrac{abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$. We know that $2 \leq S \leq 4$. We can take $a=x+1,b=y+1,c=z+1,d=t+1$. Therefore $1\leq x < y < z <t$ and $$ S=\dfrac{(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)(t+1)-1}{xyzt} = 1+ \dfrac1x + \dfrac1y + \dfrac1z+ \dfrac1t \\ + \dfrac1{xy} + \dfrac1{xz} + \dfrac1{xt}+\dfrac1{yz}+\dfrac1{yt}+\dfrac1{zt} + \dfrac1{xyz} + \dfrac1{xyt}+ \dfrac1{xzt}+\dfrac1{yzt}+\dfrac1{xyzt} \tag{1}$$

Since $1\leq x < y < z <t$, $S < 1 + \dfrac4x + \dfrac{6}{x^2}+ \dfrac{4}{x^3}$ we find that

$$(S-1)x^3< 4x^2 +6x + 4 \tag2$$.

**$1.$ CASE:** If we put $S=2$ in $(2)$, then $x^3< 4x^2 +6x + 4 $ and $x \in \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$.

**$1.a$ Case:** If we put $x=1$ in $(1)$, $1 = 1 + \dfrac11 + \dfrac1y + \cdots $

This is a contradiction. There is no solution.

**$1.b$ Case:** If we put $x=2$ in $(1)$, $$\dfrac12 =  \left(\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \left(\dfrac{1}{yz} + \dfrac{1}{yt} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \dfrac{1}{2yzt} \tag3$$

Since $3\le y < z < t$, by $(3)$ we find that $\dfrac12 < \dfrac{9}{2y} + \dfrac{9}{2y^2} + \dfrac{1}{2y^3}$ and then $y^3< 9y^2 + 9y + 1$. Therefore $y \in \{ 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$

If $y=3$ in $(3)$ we find $\dfrac12 =  \left(\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \left(\dfrac{1}{3z} + \dfrac{1}{3t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \dfrac{1}{6zt} $. But $LHS < RHS$ and there is no solution.

If If $y=4$ in $(3)$ we find $\dfrac12 =  \left(\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \left(\dfrac{1}{4z} + \dfrac{1}{4t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \dfrac{1}{8zt} $. With some algebra we yields $2z=15+\dfrac{238}{2t-15}$. There is no solution.

This sub-case has $y=5,6,7,8,9$ sub-cases. You have to examine these. For example, last value $y=9$. By $(3)$, $\dfrac12 =  \left(\dfrac{1}{9} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \left(\dfrac{1}{9z} + \dfrac{1}{9t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \dfrac{1}{18zt} $ and we yields $15zt=60(z+t) + 56$. But this gives a cotratiction in $\pmod {5}$. There is no solution.

**$1.c$ Case:**  We put $x=3,S=2$ in $(1)$,

**$1.d$ Case:**  We put $x=4,S=2$ in $(1)$,

**$1.e$ Case:**  We put $x=5,S=2$ in $(1)$,

**$2.$ CASE:** We put $S=3$ in $(2)$, then $2x^3< 4x^2 +6x + 4 $ and $x \in \{ 1,2,3 \}$.

**$2.a$ Case:** We put $x=1,S=3$ in $(1)$,

**$2.b$ Case:** We put $x=2,S=3$ in $(1)$,

**$2.c$ Case:** We put $x=3,S=3$ in $(1)$.

**$3.$ CASE:** We put $S=4$ in $(2)$, then $3x^3< 4x^2 +6x + 4 $ and $x \in \{ 1,2 \}$. Let's solve some sub-cases,

**$3.a$ Case:** We put $x=1,S=4$ in $(1)$. 
$$4 =  1+ 1+ \left(\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot 2 + \left(\dfrac{1}{yz} + \dfrac{1}{yt} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot 2 + \dfrac{1}{yzt} \tag{4}$$ 
Since $2\le y < z< t$, by $(4)$ we yields $2+ \dfrac{6}{y}+ \dfrac{6}{y^2}+\dfrac{1}{y^3}$ and hence $y \in\{ 2,3\}$.

For $y=2$, in $(4)$: $4=1+1+\left(\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot 2 + \left(\dfrac{1}{2z} + \dfrac{1}{2t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot 2 + \dfrac{1}{2zt} $ and $2zt = 6(z+t) + 3$. This is a contradiction in $\pmod{2}$.

For $y=3$, in $(4)$: $4=1+1+\left(\dfrac{1}{3} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot 2 + \left(\dfrac{1}{3z} + \dfrac{1}{3t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot 2 + \dfrac{1}{3zt} $ and ...e.t.c.

**$3.b$ Case:** We put $x=2,S=4$ in $(1)$.  We find $$ 4= 1 +\dfrac12+ \left(\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac1z + \dfrac1t \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \left(\dfrac{1}{3z} + \dfrac{1}{3t} + \dfrac{1}{zt} \right) \cdot \dfrac32 + \dfrac{1}{3zt}\tag{5}$$
Also $3\le y< z< t $ and therefore $\dfrac52 + \dfrac{1}{2y}+ \dfrac{1}{2y^2}+ \dfrac{1}{y^3}$ gives $5y^3<y^2+y+2$. There is no $y$.

Probable solutions may be in my unwriting cases. Finally we add $1$ all varibles of $(x,y,z,t)$. That is $(a,b,c,d)=(x+1,y+1,z+1,t+1)$.

Comment: So which case gives us the solution $(2,4,10,80)$? which case gives $(3,5,17,255)$?

Comment: @Alex , For $(a,b,c,d)=(2,4,10,80)$, $S=3$. If $S=3$ then $x \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $a\in \{2,3,4\}$. This is in unwriting 2.b sub-case. Also for $(3,5,17,255)$, you may calculate $S$, then we can determine it in which sub-case.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, scarface. Though this solution is long, I've learned nice technique that is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with the condition $a<b<c<d$ :

$a, b, c, d$ are either all odd or all even, as commented by TMM helps reduce the casework.

Let $M = \frac{abcd-1}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} > \frac {abcd-acd}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} = \frac {acd(b-1)}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} = \frac {acd}{(c-1)(d-1)} > a$

Since $M \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so $M \geq a+1$.

Let $S = \frac {abcd-1}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$

$ 1<S \leq \frac{(2\cdot4\cdot 6\cdot 8)-1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7} = 3.6...$

Since $S \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, so $S = 2, 3$

Find the upper bound of the smallest positive integer, $a$.

If $a \geq 5, S < \frac {abcd}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)} \leq \frac{5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdot 11}{4\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdot 10} =1.8...$

$1<S<1.8$  so there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

If $a = 4, S < \frac {4\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdot 10}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9} =2.03...$

$1<S<2.03$  so $S = 2 = \frac {M}{a-1} = \frac {M}{4-1}$  so $ M = 6 $

If $a = 3, S < \frac {3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8} =2.4...$

$1<S<2.4$  so $S = 2 = \frac {M}{3-1}$  so $M = 4$

If $a = 2, S < \frac {2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8} {1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7} =3.6...$

$1<S<3.6$  so $S = 2,3 = \frac {M}{2-1}$  but $M \geq a+1$ so $M = 3$

There are 3 cases :

Case 1 : $a=2, M=3=\frac {2bcd-1}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$

$b=4$:$\frac{8cd-1} {3(c-1)(d-1)} = 3 $, $c=9+\frac {71}{d-9}$, we have $d=80, c=10$

$b=6 $:$\frac{12cd-1} {5(c-1)(d-1)} = 3 $, $c=5+\frac {59}{3d-15}$, there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+ $.

$b>=8$ :$M <\frac{2\cdot8\cdot 10\cdot 12}{7\cdot 9\cdot 11} = 2.7...$ so 
$3=M<2.7$, there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+ $.

Case 2 : $a=3, M=4=\frac {3bcd-1}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$

$b=5$ : $\frac{15cd-1} {4(c-1)(d-1)} = 4 $ so $c=16+\frac {239}{d-16}$, we have d=255, c=17

$b=7$ : $\frac{21cd-1} {6(c-1)(d-1)} = 4 $ so $c=8+\frac {167}{3d-24}$,  there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

$b=9$ : $\frac{27cd-1} {8(c-1)(d-1)} = 4 $ so $5c=32+\frac {859}{5d-32}$,  there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

$b>=11$ : $M < \frac {3\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 15}{10\cdot 12\cdot 14} = 3.8...$ so $4=M<3.8$, there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+ $.

Case 3 : $a=4, M=6= \frac {4bcd-1}{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}$

$b=6$ : $\frac{24cd-1} {5(c-1)(d-1)} = 6 $ so $c=\frac {30d-31}{6d-30}$, there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

$b\geq8$ : $M < \frac {4\cdot 8\cdot 10\cdot 12}{7\cdot 9\cdot 11} = 5.5...$ so $6=M<5.5$, there is no solution in $\mathbb{Z}^+ $.

Ans $ (a, b, c, d) = (2,4,10,80), (3,5,17,255)$

Comment: Congratulations! @carat  , your solution better than my solution (+1)

Comment: @scarface, thank you. Your answer made me not give up. :)